# How to enable certain options in a select when users chooses an option in other select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how something like this would work using pure JS or using jQuery (I think if possible through jQuery it would be done faster?). If I have a select drop down list and the user chooses an option, based on that option the next drop down list only has certain options enabled.

Example, I am attending an event in Ontario:

```
<select name="select_province_dropdown" id="select_province_dropdown" size="1" style="width: 183px;">
    <option value="----Select Province----">----Select Province----</option>
    <option value="AB">AB</option>
    <option value="BC">BC</option>
    <option value="MB">MB</option>
    <option value="NL">NL</option>
    <option value="NS">NS</option>
    <option value="ON">ON</option>
    <option value="PE">PE</option>
    <option value="SK">SK</option>
</select>

<select name="venue_dropdown" id="venue_dropdown" size="1" style="width: 274px;">
    <option value="----Select Venue----">----Select Venue----</option>
    <option value="Toronto West">Toronto West</option>
    <option value="Vancouver">Vancouver</option>
    <option value="Edmonton">Edmonton</option>
    <option value="Toronto East">Toronto East</option>
</select>
```

So using the above HTML, I would select "ON" for Ontario, and then only Toronto West and Toronto East should show or be enabled. The selected options do not need to be displayed in any other additional areas, the user just needs to make the selections and then move on in the form. My concern is if I have 300 events across the country that will be a long list to go through even with options disabled.

What I've tried: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2v7kbv4z/4/)

The issue I see with what I've tried is that there will be a lot && statements...it works but when I have 30, 50, 100+ events I don't think it'll be ideal, also I don't know what to put in the else if I do use that.

---Background information---

A little background info as to WHY I want to try this incase anyone is wondering. I will eventually have up to 170-200 locations and I think it's easier for our users to select the correct venue by disabling options based on province. Originally I had created separate `selects` for the venues and then hid them all, and depending on which province you chose the `select` with the events associated with that province would reveal itself.

The js I have for that:

```
$('#select_province_dropdown').on('change', function() {
    if ($("#select_province_dropdown").val() === "AB") {
        $(".hideAB").attr("style", "display: block;");
    } else {
        $(".hideAB").attr("style", "display: none;");
    }
});
```

Now the issue is that the CMS we're using limits the amount of custom fields we can build for our reports, and we have to pay (a lot) to increase that which is not in the budget at the moment. So while this method is simpler and easier for me to understand, I think the other method above that I am trying to figure out how to do is better cost wise because then we have only two custom fields (two selects) which saves the company money that I don't want them to spend just because I'm such a noob, I'd rather they pay for the additional custom fields for something more important.

Comment: I 'd need to know more about the CMS revenue model. Precisely how do they charge?

Comment: Hi Roamer, I'm not sure about that, that's info my director and a few others who were in that meeting will have. I was just told that it was a lot.

Comment: The actual amount isn't important, just what is charged for and what's not. ... but you appear to have an answer now so please don't go out of your way to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the ability to add attributes to the venue dropdown, you can add a data attribute specifying which state the venue should be shown for.

Add some CSS that hides the disabled options and change the JavaScript to show only enable options that have the correct data attribute value.

Here is a demo https://jsfiddle.net/kf5tqdw2/6/

HTML

```
<select name="select_province_dropdown" id="select_province_dropdown" size="1" style="width: 183px;">
    <option value="----Select Province----">----Select Province----</option>
    <option value="AB">AB</option>
    <option value="BC">BC</option>
    <option value="MB">MB</option>
    <option value="NL">NL</option>
    <option value="NS">NS</option>
    <option value="ON">ON</option>
    <option value="PE">PE</option>
    <option value="SK">SK</option>
</select>

<select name="venue_dropdown" id="venue_dropdown" size="1" style="width: 274px;">
    <option value="----Select Venue----">----Select Venue----</option>
    <option data-for="ON" value="Toronto West">Toronto West</option>
    <option data-for="BC" value="Vancouver">Vancouver</option>
    <option data-for="AB" value="Edmonton">Edmonton</option>
    <option data-for="ON" value="Toronto East">Toronto East</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#select_province_dropdown').on('change', function() {
    var state = $("#select_province_dropdown").val();
    $("#venue_dropdown option").attr("disabled","disabled");
    $("#venue_dropdown option[data-for='" + state + "']").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

CSS

```
option[disabled] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: oh wow and it shortens the length of the drop down! this is brilliant!! I don't have direct access to the html but I'm sure I can use jquery to add the data-for attribute like I did for the Input fields something similar to `$("label [for='name']").html("dohtmlstuff");` right??

Comment: Okay, you will need a list of all the venues for each state.  You can then use this list to either add the attribute to the HTML or directly power the option filtering from it.

Comment: Here is a demo using a JavaScript object instead of HTML attributes https://jsfiddle.net/b087khL3/8/

Comment: This is fantastic Josh, it's so much cleaner than what I'm currently doing too. Thank you so much! I managed to get it to work on our form, so far no issues, all reports are coming in cleanly!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an 'onclick' function in each option.

```
    <option onclick='show(this)' data-id1='AB' value="AB">AB</option>
```

Then your 'show function' would set the second menu with the option "id='whatever'" to

```
    style='display:block'
```

where it was previously set to display:none
 I hope this simple solution helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

Set a class on all of your venue locations that matches the province they're located in:

```
<option class="ON" value="Toronto West">Toronto West</option>
```

When you select a province pull the value, disable all of the venues then re-enable only the venues that have a class matching the option value.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion Culyx! if I am unable to use Josh's method I think this is the quickest approach.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement and constraints correctly, and building on @Josh Cronin's solution ...

You might consider showing/hiding #venue_dropdown options, rather than enabling/disabling.

The code is fairly straightforward ...

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var $venue_dropdown = $('#venue_dropdown');
    $('#select_province_dropdown').on('change', function() {
        $venue_dropdown.get(0).selectedIndex = 0; // select the ----Select Venue---- option
        $venue_dropdown.find('option')
        .not(':first') // ignore the ----Select Venue---- option
        .hide() // hide all venue options
        .filter("[data-for='" + $(this).val() + "']") // select venues in the selected Province
        .show(); // show selected venues
    }).trigger('change'); // initialise #venue_dropdown in accordance with #select_province_dropdown's initial selection
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kf5tqdw2/14/)**

IMHO this will provide a better User Experience, especially if the list of venues is long.